# ALter table conflict with the foriegn key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I update my database I got an error that

> 'The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_CandidateProfiles_CandidateStatus_StatusId". The conflict occurred
> in database "CloudSourceHRM", table "dbo.CandidateStatus", column
> 'Id'.'

I am just expecting that when I perform update database I just want a table namely candidate profile and with in that I want a column namely `statusId` with foreign key connection

```csharp
public class CandidateProfile : BaseEntity
{
    [KEY]
    public Guid int{get;set;}
    
    public Guid StatusId{get;set;}
    
    public CandidateStatus CandidateStatus{get;set;}
}

public class CandidateStatus:BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id{get;set;}
    
    public string StatusName{get;set:}
    
    public ICollection<CandidateProfile>CandidateProfile{get;set;}
}

public class CloudSourceHrmDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CandidateProfile> CandidateProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CandidateStatus> CandidateStatus { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CandidateProfile>().HasOne(profile => profile.CandidateStatus).WithMany(status => status.CandidateProfile).HasForeignKey(profile => profile.StatusId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This questions is not clear. What are you trying to do, update the Status Id?

Comment: Please add the table definition and alter table statement as text, and if you know where the foreign key is publish that table as well. The Conditions and Restrictions can be found here -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: The error message definitely does not come from mysql. Reference to dbo schema suggests that you have a microsoft sql server.

Comment: You are trying to update the value of the key column with a value that does not exist in the table with the primary keys.